# How to show current position(GPX file) with the html player playing

Tags: openlayers-3

Well, here is the thing. I'm now doing a project named html5 player with real time Gps showing on the map. It means that I need to show the current position on the map when the video is playing. Video file and Gpx file related to it are on my hands. I have already realized the player part and I have successfully added a map below the player. The map can already show the track of the video. What I need to do next is to show the position on the map(maybe a marker or icon on the map,showing that you are moving) with the video playing. They should be synchronized. So is there any function or method in Ol3 can realize this? What I have in my mind is that I parse the GPX file to extract time data and position data and then match the video file's current time to it. But it's kind of lot of calculation. I would appreciate that if u guys could help me out wiz this!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this sample:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/feature-move-animation.html

if you have calculated the path of your point, i suggest you use the map postcompos event to keep a smooth rendering

Comment: Well, the path is actually the GPS track and it is added to the map as a layer by reading GPX file. Ol3 has its method to load the track to the map. What i have done already is that I check the video time every second and find the geolocation of the time point according to GPX file(It can be read as an XML file). And set the geometry of the icon every second. But although the xml file has many tags containing time and position data, the time tag update like every 5 or 6 seconds. So the icon may update too slow and jump to next position after 5 seconds. So is there anyway to make it smooth?